Evaluating a definite integral involving the fractional part function
I am looking for a closed form for the following integral $$I = \int_2^\infty \frac{\cos(\ln(\ln x))e^{\sinh[\ln x]}}{\sqrt{1+x^4}(1+x^{\cosh\{\ln x\}})}dx,$$ where $[x]$ and {x} are respectively the greatest integer and fractional part functions. I have tried splitting up the integral into two parts $I_1$ and $I_2$ where
$$
\begin{align}
I_1 &=\int_2^e \frac{\cos(\ln(\ln x))e^{\sinh[\ln x]}}{\sqrt{1+x^4}(1+x^{cosh\{lnx\}})}dx \\ &=\int_2^e \frac{\cos(\ln(\ln x))e^{\sinh[\ln x]}}{\sqrt{1+x^4}(1+x^{\cosh(\ln x - [\ln x])})}dx \\ &=\int_2^e \frac{\cos(\ln(\ln x))}{\sqrt{1+x^4}(1+x^{\cosh(\ln x)})}dx, 
\\I_2 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{e^n}^{e^{n+1}} \frac{\cos(\ln(\ln x))e^{\sinh(n)}}{\sqrt{1+x^4}(1+x^{\cosh(\ln x)-n})}dx.
\end{align}$$
But I have no idea how to proceed from here. Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Where does this integral come from?

It was sent to me by a friend when we were swapping problems for fun. I believe he got it from an old competition, but I'm not sure which one.

Do you think that it converges ?

It's hard to say if $I_2$ converges or not. I tried bounding it to check for convergence, but so far I haven't had any luck.
